# Public assets with Capistrano and Rails not being uploaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, capistrano

I have several sounds files that are located in public/assets/sounds.

Locally everything works fine, but when I deploy via Capistrano to my ec2 instance, none of those assets make it to the server. I added 'public/assets/sounds' to :linked_dirs in deploy.rb. A directory shows up at 'public/assets/sounds' but none of the mp3s are there. Do I need to manually add all files via :linked_files?

I have it working by just loading the files into the shared/public/assets/sounds directory via ftp, but that doesn't seem like the best use of the Capistrano. I'm also new to Capistrano and could be totally wrong :p

Comment: Could you post your config files so we are able to help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `public/assets` directory is reserved for the Rails asset pipeline. You should not place any files there. Here's what I would do:

1. Remove `public/assets/sounds` from `:linked_dirs`.
2. Choose a different place for the mp3 files, like `public/sounds`.
3. Do not add this directory to `:linked_dirs`.